# Wordpress Custom Content Types

Tags: wordpress

After long research, no answer or hints about this question seems to be available. 
I want to have multiple image custom content types. But how to add them with jQuery? I want an option that add dynamically multiple image custom content types when you are in the user interface to add new content.

- You have the custom content type in front of you: My
- You want add a new one
- You give it a description, and want to add an image
- **Here comes my question: You add an image and you click a button to add another image input field** (in the backend)

I hope you can help me with this.

Edit: To be more specific, where, in which file do I implement the jQuery functionality to dynamically add more image upload fields. I have no clue where to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the back-end user (using wp-admin) or a front-end user (using your actual wordpress ite)?

You can use gravity forms ( http://www.gravityforms.com/ ) in combination with this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/ to create a front-end form that will allow a user to create a new taxonomy term as well as submit an image.

On the backend there is a great plugin to create duplicate fields which would allow you to do what you're describing as "You add an image and you click a button to add another image input field (in the backend)"...It's called magic fields http://magicfields.org/

Comment: I are referring to the backend. (wp-admin) I hope there are hints or tips how to implement my question. Thanks!

Comment: To be more specific, where, in which file do I implement the jQuery functionality to dynamically add more image upload fields. I have no clue where to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

What about http://podsframework.org/ its nice framework for handaling custom content type.

Comment: Thank you, I am at the moment working with this incredible handy framework!